# ORA-01031: Message 1031 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=ORA

Tags: oracle, ora-01031

While trying to connect to Oracle database with `sqlplus / as sysdba`, I get the following error:

> ORA-01031: Message 1031 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS,
>   facility=ORA

I am using Windows environment.

How I can correct this?

Comment: Where is your sqlplus binary being run from?  Is your database on the same computer?  Did you also install Instant Client (I'm not suggesting you do this if you already have the DB on the machine)?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your oracle environment is not setup correctly.  You need to set ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID environment variables.  ORACLE_HOME should point to the root directory of your client install.

Do you have your TNSNAMES.ORA configured also?

See here for similar issue: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=619126

Comment: I have checked the both the variables already. TNSSNAMES.ora is also configured .What can be wrong for throwing this error.

Comment: @user2199560 - checked how? What OS are you using - if it's something Unix-y, have you exported the variables? (`export ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/home` etc.) You might also have OS permission issues, from the ORA-01031 error you're getting. Please add info about your environment to the question (not as a further comment).

Comment: I have edited the question with enviornment.I have checked the values of ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID in windows enviornemnt variables.Apart from this,my user is already added in ora_dba group. Is there can be another setting which can cause the issue.

Comment: have you tried logging in with a complete connect string - username/password@service?  What about a user not as sysdba?

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly do not have read access to the directories under ORACLE_HOME.

The tool is unable to generate messages because it cannot read the files.